# How to fix <class 'AttributeError'> error?

Tags: python, attributes

I don't know why ım get attribute error. My code looks like clean.
Im using pyqt5. My ui codes link: [ui codes](http://dpaste.com/3QDVQVX)

Im trying for make ui calculator. 
My idle:PyCharm 2020

Backend codes:

````
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from calculatorui import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
class myApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btn_bolme.clicked.connect(self.hesapla)
        self.ui.btn_carpma.clicked.connect(self.hesapla)
        self.ui.btn_toplama.clicked.connect(self.hesapla)
        self.ui.btn_cikarma.clicked.connect(self.hesapla)


    def hesapla(self):
        sender=self.sender().text()
        result=0
        try:

            if sender.text()=="Toplama":
                result = int(self.ui.lbl_sayi1.text()) + int(self.ui.lbl_sayi2.text())
            elif sender.text()=="Çıkarma":
                result = int(self.ui.lbl_sayi1.text()) - int(self.ui.lbl_sayi2.text())
            elif sender.text()=="Çarpma":
                result = int(self.ui.lbl_sayi1.text()) * int(self.ui.lbl_sayi2.text())
            elif sender.text()=="Bölme":
                result = int(self.ui.lbl_sayi1.text()) / int(self.ui.lbl_sayi2.text())
            self.ui.txt_sonuc.setText("Sonuç: "+str(result))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            self.ui.txt_sonuc.setText("0'a bölemezsin")
        except:
            print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
def app():
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=myApp()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
app() ```
````

Comment: What's the exact error you get?  Remove your final `except` to have it raise so you can get the full message (or fix your print statement to print the actual exception rather than just its class)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you're struggling to figure out what an error is, make sure you include it in the error message. I edited it to look like the following and got a more detailed traceback:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Unexpected error:{e}", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

The traceback shows where you're having your attribute error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-387a1e8e21c9> in hesapla(self)
     81         try:
---> 82             if sender.text()=="Toplama":
     83                 result = int(self.ui.lbl_sayi1.text()) + int(self.ui.lbl_sayi2.text())

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

On closer inspection, this is where it looks like the problem is:

```
    def hesapla(self):
        sender=self.sender().text() <------!!!
        result=0
        try:
            if sender.text()=="Toplama": <---------!!!
                result = int(self.ui.lbl_sayi1.text()) + int(self.ui.lbl_sayi2.text())
```

You call `text()` on `self.sender()`, which returns a string. Then, you try to call `text()` again on the results of the first time you call it. If you get rid of `.text()` in either the first line of `hesapla` or in the if statements, that should fix your AttributeError problem. It looks like there's another problem after that, but it appears to be unrelated to the original problem.